# meta_query, number comparison, not quite working as it should

Tags: meta-query

I have a wp_query that gets all custom post types in ascending order from today, to list some events on a site of mine. While this works fine:

```
 $args = array( 'post_type'         =>  'events',
                                'posts_per_page'    =>  5,
                                'orderby'           =>  'meta_value', 
                                'order'             =>  'ASC',
                                'meta_key'          =>  'my_special_date',
                                'meta_value'        =>  date('Ymd',strtotime("today")),
                                'meta_compare'      =>  '>=' );
```

I am not getting the same results when I convert this to using meta_query, like so:

```
array(  'post_type'         =>  'events',
                'posts_per_page'    =>  5,
                'orderby'           =>  'meta_value', 
                'order'             =>  'ASC',
                'meta_query'        =>  array(
                                                array(
                                                        'key'           => 'my_special_date',
                                                        'value'         => date('Ymd',strtotime("today")),
                                                        'compare'       => '>=',
                                                        'type'          => 'NUMERIC'
                                                        )

                                            )

                 );
```

Note that I'm not comparing dates, I'm comparing numbers, as the date is in the Ymd format. the meta key is in this format. I am having some rather odd results from this - I can't quite work out what's wrong. Anything look obviously wrong to any of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

orderby => meta_key still needs to be set as meta_query does not handle ordering.

Also, I was comparing char data as numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there's no point in converting to 'meta_query' if you're dealing with a single custom field.

Secondly, 'meta_query' doesn't handle ordering.

Finally, since your date is in the 'Ymd' format, comparing them as numbers will produce incorrect results. In your initial code, they are compared as strings.

Comment: Hey scribu, thanks for answering. I know it's pointless with a single custom field. I have a few things to compare, this is all part of an ajax system that brings posts through based on certain options picked by people, hence the change. I've removed the type=numeric, and the compare is still not working. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Scrap that scribu - I've worked out what you were saying. Ordering needed to be with meta_key just like the olden days, is all. (and scrapping the numeric as you mentioned). Thanks (and thanks for your writing on it in the first place on your blog!)